# Bootstrap 3.3.4 Tooltips not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After upgrading to Bootstrap 3.3.4, all of the tool-tips stopped working on my website.

I have created a simple example of my set-up via [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aileeneverlast/zwf2ak0m/8/) with `Bootstrap 3.3.4`, and `Jquery 2.1.3`.

Please tell me, am I doing something wrong? Did something change that I have to update?

Comment: It does work : http://jsfiddle.net/zwf2ak0m/2/ (your jQuery file was loaded after bootstrap)

Comment: Not sure, what's wrong in your website. But in the fiddle it was the loading order of your external scripts. [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwf2ak0m/3/)

Comment: @AWolf Can you please try this filddle that uses the hide instead of the show http://jsfiddle.net/aileeneverlast/zwf2ak0m/10/

Comment: You can't see any action because there's no tooltip to hide. You could use `hide` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwf2ak0m/11/).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the **Order of js files**. You must include bootstrap.js **after** jquery.js.

Here is the updated [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zwf2ak0m/9/)

**JS:**

```
$('#heading').tooltip('show')
```